# How do I find the intersection of two lines in JavaScript, given their functions?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I realize this is more of a math question, but I don't have a math brain. I'm specifically interested in solving this problem in JavaScript, just for this specific case. If someone can do this for me with a simple function, I can generalize the solution myself as needed.

I have two lines on a graph. One is linear, just going straight from (0,0) to (x,x):

```
// Line 1
var f1 = function(x) {
    return x;
};
```

The other line is curved, and can be drawn like this:

```
// Line 2
var f2 = function(x) {
    var alpha = 0.3;
    return (1 - alpha) *
        (1.4 *
         1.6 ** alpha) *
        (x ** -alpha);
};
```

Given only these functions, can I write a function that gives me the co-ordinates of the point(s) at which these two lines intersect?

I've looked at things like [algebra.js](http://algebra.js.org/), but haven't been able to come up with the solution myself.

Comment: What you're trying to find is `x` when `x == f2(x)`. It will be vastly simpler to solve that with pencil and paper algebraically.

Comment: @Vasan doesn't it seem like that could take a while? That `f2()` function returns non-integer values.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. I missed that part

Comment: @NicoSchertler thanks but I'm looking for a solution in the form of a JavaScript function. This is for a custom application I'm making. And besides, in the wolfram alpha link you posted I'm getting the error "Standard computation time exceeded..."

Comment: @NicoSchertler ?? He's already got the code for both functions. Solving the algebra for the functions gets you the value for `x` (and hence the value for y, which is `f2(x)`) and then you don't need any code.

Comment: If anyone has a complete solution, then just post an actual answer. It's not helpful to go back and forth in the comments.

Comment: 1) Are lines really defined as functions rather than by providing corresponding coefficients? 2) Are those functions fixed? (so can you just compute the answer once using some outside tool? 3) If not, are at least shapes of those lines fixed? If the answer to this is "no" as well I think this problem has no solution: there is no general way to solve arbitrary equation (and not fixed shapes means you can effectively get any equation).

Comment: @nnyby Are you looking for a general purpose solution (so working for functions with different `alpha`s) or merely a solution for `f2` here

Comment: @JoeIddon Currently `alpha` is fixed at 0.3, so the solution can take that into account. This parameter will be user-configurable in the future, though.

Comment: @SergGr thanks for the insight. That's what I was afraid of :-/ I'll have to figure out a different way to go about my problem.

Comment: @nnyby, the meta-problem is that if `f1` and `f2` can really be arbitrary code, then it can even be a piece of code that never returns (like endless loop `while (true);`). Moreover the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is famously undecidable so you can't even analyze the code from the outside to know if it always returns let alone finding intersections. To make this problem solvable you really need to restrict what functions can you use and then preferable define them not as code but as a set of parameters.

Comment: @NicoSchertler your formula has `(x^alpha)` but should be `(x^-alpha)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derivating process:
[image]

So, for `alpha= a= 0.3` we have:

```
k= (1-alpha) * 1.4 * 1.6**alpha = 1.12839738

x= k ** (1/(1 + alpha)) = 1.09737595
```

The desired intersection is {x, f(x)} = {1.0974, 1.0974}